# How to define a TFormatSettings constant (Delphi 10)

Tags: delphi, constants, record, delphi-10-seattle, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm just trying to convert a Delphi 2007 application to Delphi 10. IN the 2007 version of the software I use a constant of TFormatSettings. Since the TFormatSettings type changed somewhere in between I came across the following problem:
How do I define a TFormatSettings constant? I tried the following:

```
  XML_FormatSettings : TFormatSettings = (
    CurrencyString:            '€';
    CurrencyFormat:            3;
    CurrencyDecimals:          2;
    DateSeparator:             '-';
    TimeSeparator:             ':';
    ListSeparator:             ';';
    ShortDateFormat:           'yyyy-MM-dd';
    LongDateFormat:            'dddd, d. MMMM yyyy';
    TimeAMString:              '';
    TimePMString:              '';
    ShortTimeFormat:           'hh:nn:ss';
    LongTimeFormat:            'hh:nn:ss';
    ShortMonthNames:           ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');
    LongMonthNames:            ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Augut', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
    ShortDayNames:             ('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
    LongDayNames:              ('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
    EraInfo:                   (
      EraName:   '';               // <= Error here
      EraOffset: 0;
      EraStart:  0;
      EraEnd:    0;);
    ThousandSeparator:         ',';
    DecimalSeparator:          '.';
    TwoDigitYearCenturyWindow: 0;
    NegCurrFormat:             8;
    NormalizedLocaleName:      '';);
```

This gives the following error: Undeclared identifier: 'EraName'

I tried several other approaches but did not find a solution. Is it possible at all to define a constant of TFormatSettings? How do you handle a record type defined and used in a record type when declaring a constant?

Comment: You can predefine with a specific locale, like `FS := TFormatSettings.Create('en-US');` that suits (or alter what is needed).

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to define a constant and not a variable. This would be my last rescue (kind of).

Comment: I think you can't define it as a constant. `EraInfo` is declared as dynamic array of a record and I am not aware of any way to declare that in a constant record.

Comment: If `EraInfo` is not needed (asian date-time conversions), just remove that from the constant declaration.

Comment: @LU RD: Thanks, that will do the trick for me at the moment! What is the default if none is defined?

Comment: `TFormatSettings = ()` means default for all fields. Dynamic arrays,strings etc, will be empty. Other simple types will be zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EraInfo` is a dynamic record array, and it is not possible to define a constant dynamic record array.
If the `EraInfo` is not needed, just omit the declaration:

```
XML_FormatSettings : TFormatSettings = (
    CurrencyString:            '€';
    CurrencyFormat:            3;
    CurrencyDecimals:          2;
    DateSeparator:             '-';
    TimeSeparator:             ':';
    ListSeparator:             ';';
    ShortDateFormat:           'yyyy-MM-dd';
    LongDateFormat:            'dddd, d. MMMM yyyy';
    TimeAMString:              '';
    TimePMString:              '';
    ShortTimeFormat:           'hh:nn:ss';
    LongTimeFormat:            'hh:nn:ss';
    ShortMonthNames:           ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');
    LongMonthNames:            ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Augut', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
    ShortDayNames:             ('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
    LongDayNames:              ('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
    ThousandSeparator:         ',';
    DecimalSeparator:          '.';
    TwoDigitYearCenturyWindow: 0;
    NegCurrFormat:             8;
    NormalizedLocaleName:      '');
```

Omitted fields will be either zero or nil, depending on their type.